# xargs -I replace-str option difference

Tags: bash, xargs

From my understanding, the following should mean exactly the same:

```
ls -1 | xargs file {}
ls -1 | xargs -I{} file {}
```

if -I option is not specified, it is default to -I{}.

I want to list all files in the current directory and run `file` command on each of them. Some have spaces in their names. However, I noticed the difference. See below:

```
$ ls -1
Hello World
$ ls -1 | xargs file {}
{}:    ERROR: cannot open `{}' (No such file or directory)
Hello: ERROR: cannot open `Hello' (No such file or directory)
World: ERROR: cannot open `World' (No such file or directory)
$ ls -1 | xargs -I{} file {}
Hello World: directory
```

With -I{} explicitly specified, blanks in file names are treated as expected.

Comment: "if -I option is not specified, it is default to -I{}" -- this is incorrect, at least with GNU xargs.

Comment: I understand my mistake. I should specify either `xargs file` or `xargs -I{} file {}`. Shouldn't be `xargs file {}`. I guess when explicitly specifying -I{}, the bash will treat it as `file "Hello World"`. Without -I{}, it is treated as `file Hello World`.

Comment: (1) This discussion has little to do with the shell (bash).  (2) It’s good that you know the `-1` option to `ls`, but it’s on by default when the output of `ls` is a file or a pipe, so you don’t need it here.  (3) You’re confusing `-I` with the deprecated `-i` (lower case `I`) option.  `-ifoo` is equivalent to `-Ifoo`, but plain `-i` is equivalent to `-I{}`.  But use `-I{}`.  (4) If you really want to do what you say you want to do, why not just say `file *`?

Comment: @Scott My original intent was to write ` find . -name "*.mov" | xargs -I{} file {}` to find all mov files recursively and run `file` on them. But I came up with a simpler example using `ls`. You are right. For that, `file *` is the best.

Comment: **find** has `-exec`.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu I knew that. But I always forget the {} \ after -exec so I always prefer to go with xargs.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Actually I started using -exec these days. It is handy sometimes and I don't find \; to end the -exec part confusing anymore. Thanks for mentioning that.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `-I` requires a defined placeholder.  The `-i` option will assume `{}` is the placeholder.  This was where I found any assumption of {} in `man xargs` at least on Cygwin and CentOS.

xargs called without either option does not need the placeholder and it just appends the STDIN to the end of the arguments.

Just add `echo` to your examples to see what xargs is doing:

```
$ ls -1
Hello World/
```

Your example mistakenly uses `{}`:

```
$ ls -1 | xargs echo file {}
file {} Hello World/
```

so the `file` cmd sees args of `{} Hello World` and errors.

If you want to explicitly use `{}` in your xargs call:

```
$ ls -1 | xargs -I{} echo file {}
file Hello World/
```

Or with No placeholder:

```
$ ls -1 | xargs echo file
file Hello World/
```

xargs as called above does not need the {}. It appends the STDIN to the end of the command without a placeholder.  The use of {} usually means you want the STDIN somewhere in the middle of the cmd to execute, as in:

```
$ ls -1 | xargs -i mv {} /path/to/someplace/.
```

Comment: That is very clear. Even though your answer is a bit late, but reading it really reinforces my understanding.

Comment: According to the man page, the `-i` argument is deprecated and shouldn't be used.